# TDD: Number of Asserts, and what to actually assert?

Tags: .net, tdd, nunit, moq, assert

I am currently writing tests using TDD and I have come up against a few queries.

Normally when writing unit tests, i always used to use 1 assert per unit tests as this is what is defined as good practice and its easy to see why your test is failing.

In TDD, is it also good practice to do the same, if this is the case then to effectively design 1 method using TDD I am going to end up with more than 1 unit test - as I would effectively need more than 1 assert.

The other concern is what do I actually assert ?

I could assert what i think the return object could be ?

So I would have to create the return type (could be complex with many properties) and ensuring that these match on the assert, this could be technically 1 assert.

Or the other way would be to ensure that my mocks that i have made up along the way are actually being called i.e. en MOQ I could do the following

```
     myServiceMock.Verify(x => x.ItemsReceived(), Times.Once());
```

So i can ensure that a method is called ONLY ONCE on my mock, this is actually really classed as an assert. So it goes back to the original query, 1 assert per unit test so I would need to create additional unit tests to ensure that other methods on other mocks are being called.

What is everyone else doing here ?

Do you assert that methods are called on mocks or that the values being returned as what you expect.

Really look forward to any input anyone has on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see that your question has different concerns that I would like to cover.

First, regarding the one-assert-per-test. There is different thinking about if it's good practice or not. Fact is, it makes things overly complex when followed strictly. TDD should help you to design good and clean code, but not make you rigidly adhere to certain principles.
You can read about this topic in Robert Martin's clean code [here](http://books.google.de/books?id=_i6bDeoCQzsC&pg=PT291&dq=single%20assert%20rule%20clean%20code&hl=de&sa=X&ei=dBImUqWpCYSEtQaduoH4BQ&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=single%20assert%20rule%20clean%20code&f=false).

Second, whether you want to see what happens inside an object using a mocking framework or just asserting certain values depends on what kind of test you are writing.

You can classify tests in either tests that verify state or tests that verify behavior.

- For state-based tests you will check certain values that are relevant for the test, e.g. if my add function returned the right value.
- For behavior-based test you use mock objects to verify behavior, because the outcome usually isn't trivial to verify with production code, e.g. think about how you would automatically verify data that outputted directly to a device like a modem or a monitor.

Check Martin Fowler's excellent article [Mocks Aren't Stubs](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html) about this topic.

Third, to be honest I am not exactly sure what you mean by saying:

> In TDD, is it also good practice to do the same, if this is the case then to effectively design 1 method using TDD I am going to end up with more than 1 unit test - as I would effectively need more than 1 assert.

I assume that you think that you only have to write a single test of a new method you want to implement, which would be insane. Just think about implementing a divide function. How would you make sure that the division works properly and that in the case of division by 0 an error is generated? This would be impossible. That means that you need at least two tests for this method.

Fourth, "Test" in test-driven development is a very biased term. In general people tend to believe that in TDD you define tests to make sure that your code is not broken which is usually a task for testers not developers. However, in TDD you should rather consider that a unit test is defining behavior for a method or class that is not yet implemented.

The difference seems trivial, but it is a very powerful statement. It moves you in a position to tell the program what you expect before you actually program a single line of code. Think about it, let it sink in and try it. It makes a huge difference.
BDD was created out of this thinking. However, it is much more. You can get more details about BDD from it's inventor Dan North in [this](http://www.infoq.com/interviews/dan-north-bdd) excellent presentation.

All of this is not only my view of things, but also the view of great software developers. So, I hope it gives you a good perspective on TDD and helps you to proceed on your journey,

Answer (score 6):

This is a common problem for all guys writing tests.

*In my opinion* (I know there are many others) the one-assert-per-test-dogma (1A/T) is valid for basic unit tests, like `1 + 1 = 2`. As the level towards the full application scale increases, such as in *integration or system tests*, this is not going to work anymore. But that's maybe not your scope.

To give the problem a face:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TwoAsserts()
{
    int a = 42;
    int b = 17;

    int quotient;
    int remainder;

    quotient = Math.DivRem(a, b, out remainder);

    Assert.AreEqual(2, quotient, "quotient is wrong");
    Assert.AreEqual(8, remainder, "remainder is wrong");
}
```

What would be your alternative for the two asserts?

Doing two tests with the same input but different asserts? **For sure not.**

Writing a specialized assert method (like you mentioned) that checks all outputs and fails afterwards? **Maybe.**

But you should bear in mind that a test should be easily understandable and maintainable. Everybody reading the test - including beginners or not so tech guys - should clearly see what you are going to test and what your input, output and assertions are.

> “Code is read much more often than it is written” (and so are tests)

Also, who cares whether you have the remainder passing, when the quotient assertion fails? Does this mean you passed 50%? No, in terms of quality this would be 100% wrong. So, go ahead fix your software and run the test again. *Green? Good!*

To conclude: Keep your tests simple and use as least assertions as possible, but as many as needed. **Everything that keeps you from writing tests is evil.**