# Unit testing complicated methods, what to test and what to assume?

Tags: java, unit-testing

Consider the function [`private void create (List<T> items)`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/39364/inorder-traversal-of-a-tree-without-recursion-or-stack). This code basically creates a tree provided an BFS traversed list. Now, assume this code returned `root` and we could verify that it created tree, but doing traversals and verifying traversals match expectations. So far so good.

But :

1. Since this function is very complicated, should we be bother to test/verify that `leftIndex` and `rightIndex` calculations are done accuratately ?
2. If yes, then how to test those inner details of a function ?

In general, given a complex function, how to test the inner calculations which contribute to return value but are hidden from the use of API / function call ?

Comment: There is another question with similar thoughts about test details (not a duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18595133/tdd-number-of-asserts-and-what-to-actually-assert/18598089#18598089

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a complicated private method that you feel would benefit from unit testing, a common approach is to make that method package-private so you can invoke it direct from a unit test. In your case, you might wish to make your traversal methods package-private, or produce a package-private getter method for `root`.

But as a general rule of thumb, you should aim to unit test the *contract* of a particular class, without worrying greatly how that is achieved. That is, you should assure the expected outputs are produced based on a known set of inputs. The assumption is that the innards are working correctly if the outputs are correct. Code coverage tools can be useful for determining if your public API tests are exercising enough of your private code.

A desire to unit test the innards of a class may be a sign that the class has grown too large and would benefit from being decomposed into smaller, more testable classes. These classes can also be package-private, thus ensuring your overall public API is unaffected.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the class has grown too large - and moving `create` into a separate class sounds like the ideal approach (for testability, readability, and the fact it gives you a clean slate on which to refactor the `create` method into smaller, less complex pieces)